# how to run gcc command in script to exe main.c

Tags: linux, scripting

I'm new in linux trying to run .C program from another directory in script. script is in home directory and .C program is in Desktop directory. here is script.

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod 777 myscript
cd /home/unifi-007/Desktop/
gcc main -o main.c
./main
```

But i'm not getting it right. how to execute main.c in script.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `gcc` is clearly wrong, it should be `gcc -o main main.c`.

BTW, `.C` is a suffix for C++ (at least for GCC it is), not C.

BTW again, normally, you do not *run* a C source file, you *compile* it, and run the executable file generated by compiler (by linker, actually).